# Getting to ABAP help in SAP Library

Tags: abap

What is the difference between the following SAP Libraries:
SAP Library - 4.6c, 2001 
http://help.sap.com/saphelp_46c/helpdata/en/e1/8e51341a06084de10000009b38f83b/frameset.htm

vs

There is no version number shown, How do i get ABAP help:
http://help.sap.com/saphelp_47x200/helpdata/en/d3/1ba390bbd1204eb572e6bce09aacce/content.htm?frameset=/en/d3/1ba390bbd1204eb572e6bce09aacce/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/e1/8e51341a06084de10000009b38f83b/plain.htm&node_id=212&show_children=true

vs

Again no version number shown, ABAP Help:
http://help.sap.com/saphelp_ca_cpd106/helpdata/en/c9/5472f6787f11d194c90000e8353423/content.htm?frameset=/en/43/41341147041806e10000000a1553f6/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/d3/2e974d35c511d1829f0000e829fbfe/plain.htm&node_id=26&show_children=true#jump26

and

Is this SAP Library: The URL is not from SAP
http://myhelp.uky.edu/bw/en/9f/dbaa1335c111d1829f0000e829fbfe/frameset.htm

This is all too confusing.
I am looking for ABAP help from SAP Library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to [Klaus Hopp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38236243/6141374) Documentation can also be accessed using TX [ABAPDOCU](http://www.sapdatasheet.org/abap/tran/abapdocu.html)

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for ABAP help for your SAP version:

- Go into your favorite ABAP editor (SE38, SE80).
- place the cursor on an ABAP keyword
- press F1

This opens a SAPGUI ABAP help window for your system.

It opens with help for the keyword you started with. You can also browse around for more ABAP keywords.

(Yes I know there are more ways. Giving someone confused exactly one way that works is a good thing).

Answer (score 3):

The best ABAP help is an ABAP Keyword documentation. It contains syntax, guidelines, best practices, code snippets and so on. Your steps for choosing the correct version of ABAP documentation are:

1. Go to *System* >> *Status* >> *Product Version* >> *Component*
2. Check versions of **SAP_ABA** and **SAP_BASIS** components and especially their *Support Package* level. Up to date major version now is 7.40 or even 7.50.

[image]

Normally these components should have the same level.

3. Go to the corresponding version of ABAP Keyword documentation:

   - [7.31](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_731/en/index.htm)
   - [7.40](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_740/en/index.htm)
   - [7.50](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_750/en/index.htm)

New features and updates corresponding to your support package level can be found in section [Release-Specific Changes](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_750/en/abennews.htm)

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to run the transaction code [**ABAPHELP**](http://www.sapdatasheet.org/abap/tran/abaphelp.html) (Search ABAP Documentation) in your SAP GUI.

You do not have to confused on different versions and patch levels and try to find the correct help document.